# Using correct words

Tags: word-usage, forms-of-address

Can students call their teacher **madam**?

Example: In a conversation between a teacher and a student.

> Student: May I open the window, **madam**? 
>   Teacher: It doesn't matter.

Do people in UK or USA use this term?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the region and local registers. In India, it's pretty a common term that students use for their teachers. Also, note that some practice 'Madam,' others use 'ma'am.' Nevertheless, I now observe that 'Miss' is also getting grounds in India these days. It's worth to note that even though a lady teacher is married, she's addressed as 'miss' by her students.

[A good read is here on BBC.](https://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-magazine-monitor-27407789)

Comment: It also depends on the teacher's preferences.  Calling your teacher something they won't tolerate can lead to scholastic difficulties.

Comment: @EdGrimm I second you...and I know someone like that as well! :)